Angular 15 Can not find column with id in mat-table with virtual-scroll?
I'm using angular material in my project and I'm using Mat-Table to render 1000 items/row per table i have already tried multiple solution but nothing worked for me,whole page stuck also showing page unresponsive if select All from pagination
Tried below solution but nothing worked for me:
1.Set data after ngAfterViewInit
2.ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
3. TrackBy
4.Already applied virtual scrolling but getting below error 

can anybody please help me regarding how to fast load data if thousand of record in mat-table



